# Any iOS Text Editors Capable of Custom Extensions?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Specifically, I'm looking for a text editor that allows me to save a file with any extension of my choosing. I recently was trying to create a .csmo file, but couldn't find a solution to create a text file with a custom extension. If there is a way to do this natively, please let me know.

If this is not the place to ask this, please point me to the correct forum.

Comment: There are several Q&As on this site about recommendations for text editors, just try those for a start. Or use Textedit.app.